# How to reduce boilerplate/repetition in TypeScript data-classes?

Tags: typescript

I am learning TypeScript (I am an experienced programmer with Kotlin/Java, Dart/Flutter, Python, and various lisps). I am stumped by the amount of boilerplate that I seem to need for TS data-classes. Here is a simplified example: I need a simple `Student(id, firstName, middleName, lastName, enrolledOn)` class. I also want:

- **named parameters for the constructor** (to make call-sites readable)
- and a `copyWith` method.

Here is what I seem to need:

```
class Student {
  constructor({
    id,
    firstName,
    middleName,
    lastName,
    enrolledOn,
  }: {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    middleName: string;
    lastName: string;
    enrolledOn?: Date;
  }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.enrolledOn = enrolledOn;
  }

  copyWith({
    id = this.id,
    firstName = this.firstName,
    middleName = this.middleName,
    lastName = this.lastName,
    enrolledOn = this.enrolledOn,
  }: {
    id?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    middleName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    enrolledOn?: Date;
  }): Student {
    return new Student({
      id,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      enrolledOn,
    });
  }
}
```

The number of times I have to repeat the same fields is 6 times! In my actual case I have some data-records with 9-10 fields (and many optional), so this really is a lot of boilerplate.

In my previous work, in Java I have used [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/), [built-in data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) in Kotlin and [Freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed) in Dart to reduce a lot of the boilerplate.

For example, the above class in Dart using Freezed would be:

```dart
@freezed
class Student with _$Student {
  const factory Student({
    required String id,
    required String firstName,
    required String middleName,
    required String lastName,
    DateTime? enrolledOn,
  }) = _Student;
}
```

I have of course asked ChatGPT etc. and came across [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) and [immutable.js](https://immutable-js.com/). But even using them, to have named constructor params and copyWith methods, the boilerplate seems to be excessive in TS?

Are there any libraries or techniques that can make managing data-classes easier? Or am I not thinking about this in a Typescript/JS-first approach?

Comment: Not using primary constructors?

Comment: D you actually need a `class` type instead of just an `interface`? Your `Student` class doesn't have any methods (only data-properties) besides `copyWith`, so a `class` is unnecessary here because your `copyWith` method is redundant: just use `Object.assign`.

Comment: I need other methods (in my actual code), so I do need a class.

Comment: Primary constructor is positional arguments, right? I want named arguments.

Comment: Object.assign is nice. IMO, `foo.copyWith(bar)` is much better reading than `Object.assign(foo, bar)` (or to have the same immutable semantic: `Object.assign({}, foo, bar`)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Probably the simplest and least controversial is to extract your inline types to an interface.

More controversial would be using `Object.assign()` as a shortcut. TypeScript has [very limited type checking capabilities when it comes to `Object.assign`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GF0hsAc2QG8AoZC5GTALmQGcwpQCBuUgX1NIQBs569NJhLlK1dDUbMQbbpWQJc0gK4Iw6KAAoleQjQzZc+AgEpRChQHkARgCsI6gHQD6hEFrAALYPQA0isaEpuwKXBxAA) (see GitHub issue [#26792](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26792)), but if you know your code well and feel comfortable with it, then this can dramatically reduce your code footprint.

```js
interface StudentConfig {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
  enrolledOn?: Date;
}

class Student implements StudentConfig {
  id!: string; // The "!" tells TypeScript that this property is set
               // even though the compiler can't tell how
  firstName!: string;
  middleName!: string;
  lastName!: string;
  enrolledOn?: Date;

  constructor(config:StudentConfig) {
    Object.assign(this, config);
  }

  // Partial<StudentConfig> makes all of the properties on
  // StudentConfig optional
  copyWith(config: Partial<StudentConfig>): Student {
    return new Student(Object.assign({}, this, config));
  }
}


// ============

const foo = new Student({
    id: "foo",
    firstName: "Foo",
    lastName: "Foo",
    middleName: "Foo",
});
const bar = foo.copyWith({
    id: "bar",
    firstName: "Bar",
}); // { id: "bar", firstName: "Bar", lastName: "Foo", middleName: "Foo" }
```

In the end, though, a lot depends on your needs. I'm giving you a reasonably short answer because it's what you asked for, but there are tradeoffs. The `Object.assign()` is not very performant, for example. And the `!` operator negates some of TypeScript's type checking ability (although making `Student` implement `StudentConfig` does help to mitigate most of that risk). So you'll have to weigh the tradeoffs for yourself.

Comment: "_TypeScript has very limited type checking capabilities when it comes to `Object.assign`_" - I know it was rough in years past, but since TypeScript 4.x I've been happy with `Object.assign`.

Comment: @Dai - Example of TypeScript Object.assign shortcomings: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GF0hsAc2QG8AoZC5GTALmQGcwpQCBuUgX1NIQBs569NJhLlK1dDUbMQbbpWQJc0gK4Iw6KAAoleQjQzZc+AgEpRChQHkARgCsI6gHQD6hEFrAALYPQA0isaEpuwKXBxAA

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is very much just static types on top of JavaScript, so it's always best to think about the limitations of TypeScript in terms of the limitations of JavaScript.

Idioms in other languages don't always translate 1-to-1. Lets explore how we can get rid of the boilerplate by making your code more idiomatic.

With JavaScript and TypeScript data objects, or DTOs (Data Transfer Objects), are often just plain old objects rather than class instances. The reason for this is it simplifies the serialization to and from JSON. You cannot deserialize into a class instance. This is similar to using `struct`s in other languages.

I am going to suggest we use plain old objects rather than classes. Student becomes an interface, and the copyWith(..) method becomes a the createStudenWith(..) function.

```js
interface Student {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
  enrolledOn?: Date;
}

function createStudentWith(student: Student, partial: Partial<Student>) {
  return { ...student, ...partial };
}

const studentA: Student = { id: 'abc', firstName: 'Joe', middleName: 'Blogs', lastName: 'Blow' };
const studentB = createStudentWith(studentA, {id: 'zyx', firstName: 'jane'}); 

console.log(studentA, studentB);
```

You can see a working example at the TypeScript Playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLmQbwChllgsAuZAZzClAHMBuY5GYKGgOTgFsJKadEExY8yWADYRufAbQbMSEuF179q84YuS4oAewlSsAeRAB+SgBE4kZgF9ChGBhAIwwPSGQIoEGxHRsXDAAdWAwAAsAChog8EpAnHAAGmQABzgodzgJSgAFTOyJAB5E4IA+AEoCFl9MKC98ZAA6VtiksFTW5oys4BzkO3tHBE8aDTiwAEEEzA7kAF4CUgpkAHI4ACMENdS2DjAZdTWAKT0IXeQxLElpNUo1gCEJPXoqS+VVWXXnvQB3NaDZijEDjdrBR6Lby+fxlcBhSIxObBKapfBkB4ALwAngAPS77L7HABWcBAFzslUYyBGYwMEGaL3oSMmqImHUeVMIQA

Comment: You've assumed that the OP doesn't need the class structure for prototypal inheritance. That might be appropriate, but your solution won't work if the OP has any methods the they omitted for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Fair enough but inheritance is inappropriate for data classes.

Comment: Do you mean inheriting from a base class, or creating instances of the data class? I just double-checked and the OP commented: "_I need other methods (in my actual code), so I do need a class._"

Comment: Or other functions.